# How do I input_shape or input_dim correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to Keras and have been struggling with shaping the data correctly. I have been trying for a few weeks now and this is the closest I have gotten. I'm pretty sure I just forced things to work and have to adjust the shape of the data. A few questions:

1. Does the model, loss, optimization, or activation function determine what shape/dimension the input_shape or input_dim needs to be?

If not how do I go about shaping the data into its correct form.

I tried shaping the data to (1, 1, 59) but then I would get complaints that the target data's shape was (1, 1, 19). For now the only way I would know how to go about that is to chop my data in half to make it an even shape but I would like to just use 20% of the data to create a new set.

My Code:
What I'm trying to do is have the model learn a sequence from 1 - 100.
Then given a number it should predict what the next number should be.

```
# Tool setup
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

# Setup our dataset and testset.
dataset = [] # Training set.
validset = [] 
testset = [] 

dataset = list(range(60))
validset = list(range(60, 80))
testset = list(range(80, 100))

# Preprocess Data:
X_train = dataset[:-1] # Drop the last element.
Y_train = dataset[1:] # The second element is the target for prediction.

# Reshape training data for Keras LSTM model
# The training data needs to be (batchIndex, timeStepIndex, dimensionIndex)
# Single batch, time steps, dimensions
#print(np.array(X_train).shape)
X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(-1, 59, 1)
Y_train = np.array(Y_train).reshape(-1, 59, 1)

# Normalize the Data:
#X_train = np.divide(X_train, 200)
#Y_train = np.divide(Y_train, 200)

X_test = validset[:-1] # Drop the last element.
Y_test = validset[1:] # The second element is the target for prediction.
#print(np.array(X_test).shape)
X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(-1, 19, 1)
Y_test = np.array(Y_test).reshape(-1, 19, 1)

# Build Model
model = Sequential()  
#model.add(LSTM(100, input_dim=1, return_sequences=True, 
activation='softmax'))
model.add(LSTM(100, input_dim=1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=["accuracy"])
#model.add(Dropout(0.80))

# Train the Model
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), 
nb_epoch=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)

# The validation set is checked during training to monitor progress, and 
possibly for early stopping, 
# but is never used for gradient descent.

# validation_data is used as held-out validation data. Will override 
validation_split.
# validation_data=(X_test, Y_test)

# validation_split is the Fraction of the data to use as held-out validation 
data.
# validation_split=0.083 

from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils.visualize_util import model_to_dot

SVG(model_to_dot(model).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))

# list all data in history
print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validate'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validate'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# Test the Model
#print(np.array(testset).shape)
testset = np.array(testset).reshape(-1, 5, 1)
predict = model.predict(testset)
# Undo the normalization step.
#predict = np.multiply(data, 200)
predict = predict.reshape(-1)
print(predict[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the model, loss, optimization, or activation function determine what shape/dimension the input_shape or input_dim needs to be?

I am leaning on the answer being Yes. Some functions require a different dimension size.

For now let's keep it simple and just focus on the spirit of the problem.

```
dataset = list(range(100))
validset = dataset[-20:]
testset = dataset[-20:]
```

It seems Keras wants the data for the LSTM to be shaped as such:
batchIndex, timestepIndex, dimensionIndex

```
print(np.array(X_train).shape)
X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(99, 1, 1)
Y_train = np.array(Y_train).reshape(99, 1, 1)
print(np.array(X_train).shape)
```

Result:
(99, )
(99, 1, 1)

Model was simplified to:

```
model = Sequential()  
model.add(LSTM(100, input_dim=1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Judging by the graphs and the incorrect prediction there's still a lot of work to do. At least this will get things started.